# Geometric meaning of minors

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, determinant

This is a bit silly question I found on another discussion forum. I know that determinants can be used to compute volumes of parallelepiped. I also know that determinants can be computed by linear combination of its minors. Is there any geometric meaning of minors or some proof/explanation why there is no such geometric meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, then consider $P_iAQ_j$, where $P_i$ is the $(n-1)\times n$ matrix obtained from removing the $i$th row from the identity matrix and  $Q_j$ is the $n\times (n-1)$ matrix obtained from removing the $j$th column from the identity matrix.

Then $P_iAQ_j$ is the $ij$ minor of $A$. So it may help you to think about the geometry related to $P_i:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ and $Q_j:\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$.